# Accessing QML TextField value in Python

Tags: python-3.x, qml, pyqt5

I have a form in QML with two TextFields. How do I access the value entered in the fields in Python?

I'm using PyQt5.5 and Python3.

```
import sys
from PyQt5.QtCore import QObject, QUrl
from PyQt5.QtWidgets import QApplication
from PyQt5.QtQuick import QQuickView
from PyQt5.QtQml import QQmlApplicationEngine


if __name__ == '__main__':
    myApp = QApplication(sys.argv)

    engine = QQmlApplicationEngine()
    context = engine.rootContext()
    context.setContextProperty("main", engine)

    engine.load('basic.qml')

    win = engine.rootObjects()[0]
    button = win.findChild(QObject, "myButton")
    def myFunction():
        print("handler called")
        foo = win.findChild(QObject, "login")
        print(dir(foo))
        print(foo.text)
    button.clicked.connect(myFunction)
    win.show()

    sys.exit(myApp.exec_())
```

### basic.qml

```
import QtQuick 2.3
import QtQuick.Controls 1.2

ApplicationWindow {
    width: 250; height: 175

    Column {
        spacing: 20
        TextField {
            objectName: "login"
            placeholderText: qsTr("Login")
            focus: true
        }

        TextField {
            placeholderText: qsTr("Password")
            echoMode: TextInput.Password
        }

        Button {
            signal messageRequired
            objectName: "myButton"
            text: "Login"
            onClicked: messageRequired()
        }
    }
}
```

### Console

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "working.py", line 25, in myFunction
    print(foo.text)
AttributeError: 'QQuickItem' object has no attribute 'text'
fish: “python working.py” terminated by signal SIGABRT (Abort)
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You need to call the [`property()`](https://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qobject.html#property) method of the object to get the desired property.

In your example, you need to call:

```
print(foo.property("text"))
```

rather than `print(foo.text)`

Note that `property()` returns `None` if the property doesn't exists.